# Android Studio 0.8.2 error "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]" when trying to load app on phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am in the process of building and debugging an app on my phone and I keep getting the error "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]" when I try to push a test build to my phone. It by default set the target SDK to L but I set the minimum SDK level to 9 to cover the most devices. The device I'm trying to load the app on is a Galaxy S3 running 4.4.4 (which I know is API 19).

Here is the defaultConfig from my build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tg94.intcalc"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion "L"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    {
```

When I go and look at my AndroidManifest.xml though, this is what it shows

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="L"
        android:targetSdkVersion="L" />
```

When I try to edit this (I tried editing in Visual Studio 2013, Notepad++ and just plan Windows Notepad), I noticed the `android:minSdkVersion` always changes back to L even though I changed it and saved it to API level 9. Is there any suggestions I should try to fix this?

EDIT: Just updated Android Studio to 0.8.2 but the problem still presists

Answer (score 2):

Currently, applications that target the L developer preview *cannot* be installed on devices that do not have it -- the SDK forces `minSdkVersion` to L when `targetSdkVersion` is L. [This](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72453) is the associated issue in the AOSP tracker.

Although there are some hacks around this limitation, such as described [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/), they basically involve fooling the SDK into thinking L is not a developer preview.

If you're developing for L, then you should use an L device (or emulator) to test the app. Otherwise, use `targetSdkVersion` 19 instead.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded and went down to API 19 and was able to get it to work

Comment: If you follow the link in matiash's Answer (a great link), you'll find this: "NOTE... The Android team has made it pretty clear that *Gradle is the future* from here on out, so if you're still on Eclipse then I don't know what to tell you." Just FYI, though I guess it's just an opinion. All these AS quirks have made me wonder if I should change to Eclipse. This blurb makes me want to stay with AS thru thick and thin. So far every AS problem has been solvable.